# How to get procedure result in another procedure without OUT parameter

Tags: mysql

I have made a procedure which returns multiple values and i want to use these values in another procedures without OUT parameter. is there any solution?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: not yet, i don't know what i can do in this case.

Comment: First of all, you should create two stored procedure. They should be run independently. After that, we'll discuss.

Comment: i have made it as i described above. i run them individually. now i want this functionality.

Comment: Now, you can call the second procedure in your first procedure, you can get the output into the first procedure.

Comment: bro, How? that's the problem.

Comment: Add your code in question, after that I can suggest you :)

Comment: bro, my code is not important, problem statement is important.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the actual type of result you want to "transfer" from one procedure to the next there are different options:

If your fist procedure produces only a small number of individual values (like a single id or a count or sum of something) you can store them in (a) variable(s) and use them for calling the next procedure. Otherwise - for data in a tabular form - you can create a temporary table which you then access from your second procedure.